how to wrap an unconstrained child in SingleChildScrollView
Below code is a root layout for every route page in cross platform app. I got an Error: "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#252b0 relayoutBoundary=up20".
Widget build(context) {
    return AutoRouter(builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
            ///Max width 1133 constraints box layout
            body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                          maxWidth: 1133, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: Svg("assets/images/background_image.svg",
                                  size: Size(1133, 744)))),
                      
                      child: child ),
                ),
              );
            })
      );
    });
  }

I realise it is cause to the child is unconstrained since every page has no fixed size. So I search for solution and found IntrinsicHeight widget to get the child size. The reason I not use SingleChildScrollView inside the child because I want user scroll at the root so that the background image would not fixed but also scroll down.
body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxWidth: 1133, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all(),
                        image: const DecorationImage(
                            repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: Svg(
                              "assets/images/background_image.svg",
                              size: Size(1133, 744),
                            ))),
                   
                    child: IntrinsicHeight(child: child);
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),

But I facing another problem that I cannot use LayoutBuilder inside the child it pop out an Error: Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out. How to use LayoutBuilder with this solution, or , any other suggestion for my case . Thank you.

Why are you using LayoutBuilder? Any specific reason?

for responsive design. In some page , I would like to put some  svg image for decoration, so I need the size of specific widget, those widget size is not fixed. therefore ,to determine the decoration position,

Can you try with Stack widget, I assume you like to have a scroll able background .

try to put the LayoutBuilder inside a SizedBox
 body: SizedBox(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 300.0,
        child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Container(
          height: constraints.maxHeight,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: 1133, minHeight: constraints.maxHeight),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                        repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        image: Svg(
                          "assets/images/background_image.svg",
                          size: Size(1133, 744),
                        ))),
               
                child: IntrinsicHeight(child: child);
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      })),

or use Expanded()
sorry for the brackets

this root layout width and height should be dynamic , determine user screen size

Thanks for the suggest , I tried add a Sizebox let MediaQuery.of(context).size be the sizebox width and height. Then I use a LayoutBuilder inside a child and got a different error: LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.. any idea?

try StateFullBuilder instead of builder in layoutbuilder

LayoutBuilder ( return StateFullBuilder (builder(...) { return AlertDialog ( your code) } ))
or u can use without Statefullbuilder  sorry idk how it works
